# HTTP Token: Access denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, access-token

i m getting message "`**HTTP Token: Access denied**`" when access via browser `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/tasks.json?auth_token=szVkqLnUbdzbekV8B-n_`
but when i access from terminal that's working on success  `curl http://localhost:3000/api/v1/moments.json -H 'Authorization: Token token="szVkqLnUbdzbekV8B-n_"'`

here code

```
  class Api::V1::TaskController < ApplicationController
          before_action :autentifikasi
    def index
        @tasks = current_user.tasks
    end
        private
          def autentifikasi
            authenticate_or_request_with_http_token('Premium') do |token, options|
               @current_user = User.find_by(authentication_token: token)

            end
          end 
        end
     end
```

anybody help me please !! what's wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with you code - the error is in your testing methodology.

The cURL example properly sends a `Authorization: Token` header and sends the token along as well.

Requesting `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/tasks.json?auth_token=szVkqLnUbdzbekV8B-n_` in a browser would simply set `params['auth_token']` as it is a *query parameter*. Which will of course cause the authentication to fail.

Rails and most sane frameworks do not treat HTTP headers and query parameters as equivalent. That would leave your app looking like swiss cheese.

If you want to test token based auth via a browser you should use a plugin such as Postman which allows you to setup the request headers. Better yet is to write an actual automated integration test.

- [A Guide to Testing Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html)
- [RSpec Rails: Request spec](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec)
- [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/introduction)

Answer (score 1):

It is because `authenticate_or_request_with_http_token` expects an `Authorization: Token` from in a `request header`.

You are setting the header in the cURL command while in browser you are passing it as a query parameter.

So there is no token in the Request Header so your method is unable to find the token when accessed via a browser.